# How to transfer phone contacts to a new phone?

Tags: contacts

Please how do I recover phone numbers previously saved on my Gmail account from my broken android phone into the new one I got. I tried syncing already, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your previous phone working. Simply export your contact to external storage this will create a .vcf file. Send the file to new android phone and just open it all contacts will be restored.

If your previous phone is damaged and you have synced your contacts it will we saved on the Google account and can be restored to new device by syncing. To check whether your google account contains your contact goto [this](http://contacts.google.com) link.

Answer (score 0):

You could move all your contacts to your SIM card. From there, just put the SIM in the New phone, and,move them back

Method

1. Go to your contacts.
2. Select "backup contacts", and select "to SIM card" and wait.
3. Once done, turn off both devices, and put the SIM card from the old phone in the New one
4. In the contacts of the New phone, press "restore" and then "from SIM card"

Done!